# WillPopScope not working with go_router web Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-go-router

```
WillPopScope(
 onWillPop: () async {
 log('WillPopScope: working in call');
  return new Future(() => true);
 }
 child: Scaffold()
)
```

I am using go_router for navigating through pages in Web. Here onWillPop seems to be never called. How can we listen when back button pressed on WEB.

Comment: I have the same issues, any update?

Comment: In latest update they have provided onExit callback. You can use this like onWillPop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `onExit`

```
          GoRoute(
          path: 'new',
          onExit: (context) {
            //
            // Some OnExit Logic like OnWillPop
            // 
            return true;
          },
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            //
            // Some OnEnter Logic 
            // 
            return NewScreen();
          }),
```

Comment: this is not like WillPopScope. WillPopScope is used from the widget page and onExit is used in the routers file, i cant access to the widget logic with the onExit.

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón your right, unfortunately we don't have any chooses. 
go_router is still in development.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same issue.

Seems like there's ongoing threads regarding this issue on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99706).
The issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102408).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be a comment not answer